# Issue on UIOrientation in ipad

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm developing the app for all the orientations in Ipad....But during the development I did only for landscape mode..But nw I want to change to all the possible orientations... Here I got some problem....
Here is the code...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
 //return YES;
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
     {
       \\Here I did my stuff..
     }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        \\Here I did my stuff..
     }
}
```

The problem is,When the simulator is launched and if itz in the landscape mode,I got the proper size of the views,but if the simulator is in potrait mode I can't get what I want... If I change the orientations of simulator I get the correct size of the views...

Comment: Try this method - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: The thing is tat I can get the resized view wen the device is changing the orientations(I thnk the above mentioned delegate ll be called wen the device is changing the orientation) ,bt I want my complier to detect orientation of the device wen the appl is gnging to be launched and change the size of the view depending on the orientations..hw can i do tis?

Comment: You must configure the struts and springs for all your views in your interface builder.

Comment: @MadhavanRP Can U plz post any links regarding the configuration

Comment: http://drupalry.com/sites/drupalry.com/files/book/2011/03/Apple_Interface_Builder_UserGuide.pdf Page 94,95. If you configure the struts and springs, you can make the user interface look right in any orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the same problem that was facing.
And i solved it by doing this:

First change this function:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

and then in the viewDidLoad function you can check whether the device is in landscape or in Portrait.

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
   {
         //landscape view code
   } 

   else
   {
        //portrait view code
   }

 }

 hope this will help
```